# how i can write if statment in unix AIX

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, aix

i want to write `if` statment as following :-

`if [$x == "string"]`

`then`

`echo "ok"`

`fi`

but the following error appear

`./bash_if.sh[6]: [0:  not found.`

Comment: I don't see how a question about bash scripting would be off-topic here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[` needs a space after it because `[` is actually a command (`/usr/bin/[` on Linux, though bash has a built-in version that it uses).  Without the space, bash converts $x to the value, then tries to run the command `[0`, just as if you had typed `lssomedir` or `echohi`.

Also, if you are testing strings, you should put quotes around $x:

```
if [ "$x" == "string" ]
```

Otherwise, if $x is empty or unset, you will get an error because without the quotes, after "expanding" $x, it will look like

```
if [ == "string" ]
```